# problem with Mysql Unknown error starting mysql and Unknown error starting apache

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, bitnami

I have problem with all version of bitnami. When I shut down or restart my pc, WAMP can't connect with MySQL. I closed skype but still have the same problem. I also changed to XAMPP but the problem still there when I shut down. In the end, I revert to bitnami and I still have the same problem. I've watched all the troubleshooting video and do something like changing port to 3307 but I can't resolve this problem.

This is the message I get from bitnami:

```
Stderr:
Unknown error starting mysql
Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 1
Stdout:

Stderr:
Unknown error starting apache
```

Answer (score 0):

could you try this?
1.- Go to the control panel->Administrative Tools -> Services,
2.- find web Deployment Service and stop it.
3.- Start the apache server in bitnami

You can check if the port it's in use with the console,
1.- click the Start button,
2.- type cmd
3.- right-click “Command Prompt” when it shows up in the search results. Click “Run as administrator.”

When the console appears copy the next command:

```
netstat -ab
```